# how to restrict user from accessing a perticular action of a controller?

Tags: grails, permissions, controller, action

HI.
I have two user's for my app.one is admin n other visitors..i have two actions in my controller.i admin can act on both but i want visitors to be restricted from accessing 2nd action.how to achieve it?

Waiting for answer with advance thanks,

Comment: use spring security core for this. but i would not advance you to do this in your use-cse. you should separate admin actions and visitor actions, e.g. in different embedded plugins.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to restrict user from accessing a particular action of a controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016625/how-to-restrict-user-from-accessing-a-particular-action-of-a-controller)

Answer (score 1):

The spring security plugin is the way to go. http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core

I would recommend using the annotation approach. There is a section on using annotations in the blog post http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/

I would recommend reading the above blog post in its entirety

E.g. Controller action would be secured like....

```
//all users
@Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'])
def firstAction = { ... }

//only admin
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
def secondAction = { ... }
```

The plugin also offers a "remember me" option if you dont want to force your users to always login

Comment: i am trying to use spring security..but i already have USER domain class in my app..and User controller,,if i try to delete that and implement its features in plug in generated user domain.my user controller wont work..what should i do?

Comment: Can u give me a link of any sample app on how to use spring security on existing User domain class

Comment: You can use your user domain by adding something like this to your Config.groovy grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.app.Person'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName = 'email'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.passwordPropertyName = 'passwd'

Comment: instead of that i extended plug in genarated user in my user domain class & merchant domain class..now i want to restrict my action named search from merchant for that i wrote **@Secured(['ROLE_MERCHANTS'])
** to search action

Comment: now when i click on search link i am getting login form generated by plug in but when i enter user name and password which is there in my merchant table.its giving error message as no user id and password found why so?

Comment: Are you using the default username and password fields from the plugin generated user? Can you supply any error logging? Make sure "ROLE_MERCHANTS" role is assigned and the password and username fields you wish to use are configured. E.g. grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName = 'email' grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.passwordPropertyName = 'passwd'

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the controllers interceptors http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1 Controllers

or install the Spring Security Core plugin http://www.grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core.

Comment: interceptors i have used for securing app with login..can i use filters

Comment: Yes, you are using filters as well, but the Spring Security Core plugin provides you all these functionalities.

Comment: I suggest to use the filters to securing your app with login. There is a sample filter doing this task here : http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.6 (Search for "Filters"). Then, you can use the controllers interceptors to restrict specific actions to admin only.

Comment: @Fabrizio: I think the SpringSecurity plugin's your good choice

Comment: 'how can i add code in comment in stack overflow.i want to show the code'

Comment: please look at code i have updated with my just proposed question.