# How to restrict user from accessing a particular action of a controller?

Tags: grails, filter, controller, action, interceptor

```
 def filters = {
   loginCheck(controller:'*', action:'*') {
        before = {
           if(!session.user && !session.merchants) 
           {
               redirect(action:'login')
               return false
            }
        }}
```

That was my filter for login security. And below is interceptor in action for restricting user from search action. But both are not working. Can any one tell what the mistake is?

```
def beforeInterceptor = [action:this.&checkUser,Only:'search']

    def scaffold = true
    def checkUser() 
    {
        if (session.user)
        {
            redirect(action:"search")
        }
        if(session.merchants)
        {
        redirect(action:"toIndex")
        flash.message="You are not valid user for this action"
        return false
        }   
    }
```

Comment: please do not post the exact same question twice.

Comment: Use the Spring Security plugin, don't try to role your own.

Answer (score 0):

actually you filter should work as it is set for every controller and every action. 
here is the grails example from the reference:

```
class SecurityFilters {
   def filters = {
       loginCheck(controller:'*', action:'*') {
           before = {
              if(!session.user && !actionName.equals('login')) {
                  redirect(action:'login')
                  return false
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

I worked with this one and it worked for me.
What I'm not sure is about the `session.merchants` in your code.
What is this ?

Did you follow this:

> To create a filter create a class that
>   ends with the convention Filters in
>   the grails-app/conf directory.

---

Edit: 
If you use spring security you don't need to add a filter or interceptor.
check the user guide: http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/index.html

you can configure it with url mappings or annotations.

ex.

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
   '/js/admin/**': ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
   '/someplugin/**': ['ROLE_ADMIN']
]
```

---

EDIT 2:

To get the logged in user use:

```
 def authenticateService

...
def action{
     def user = authenticateService.principal() 
     def username = user?.getUsername()
...
```

Comment: merchant is my other user of app other than admin.and i named my filter with end convention Filters

Comment: I thought its better to use spring security as many suggested me to try with it.i have installed it and ran s2 quickstart

Comment: there is this command i should run next **'grails s2-quickstart org.example SecUser SecRole'**..but i am not getting what should i give in secUser n secRole place n org.example should be my app name or what?

Comment: I already have a User domain class do i need to delete it to have plug in User class?

Comment: Hi Nandita. In 'grails s2-quickstart org.example' org.example should be your app name indeed. Second question, yes you could use your own User class. But I recommend to generate the User and Role class with the s2-quickstart command and add you personal code to this classes. It's the easiest way.

Comment: and i have 2 kind of user's for my app admin and merchants for that i have 2 domain classes.now do i need to create 2 domain classes in plug in

Comment: I am really not getting how to use this plug in to achieve solution for my problem.:(

Comment: is there any way in grails to find out which user has called the action?

Comment: please read the tutorial and make maybe a test-app. http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/index.html

Comment: Thanks i am fallowing tutorial...but now my problem is i have two kind of user's for my app and i have two domain classes User and merchant.i have plug in generated SecUser and SecRole class.i can make User domain to extend plug in generated but what about merchants domain?

Comment: I actually want restrict my action to merchant domain.

Comment: i tried using authenticateservice() in my controllerr action to find out login user but i got  this error.**No such property: authenticateService for class: merchant.RegisterController **

Comment: Better way would be if you use the same User class all the time and give them the role merchant. Only the User which is generated by spring-security has the authenticateService.

Comment: No such property: authenticateService for class: merchant.RegisterController

Comment: i am getting that error when i try ti use authenticate service to fin d out which user has loged in search action.why so?

Answer (score 0):

There's a really nice shorthand that you can apply directly to actions (if you're not using filters):

```
@Secured(['ROLE_USER'])
def search = {

}
```

You can give every user ROLE_USER and simply require that role.

Comment: i have just installed s2 spring secutirity

Comment: there is this command i should run next **'grails s2-quickstart org.example SecUser SecRole'**..but i am not getting what should i give in secUser n secRole place n org.example should be my app name or what?

Comment: IF i use @Secured(['ROLE_USER']) i am getting login page generated by plug in..but i am not getting its flow.when i ented user name and password of my User domain class its not loging in.am getting error msg as no user